# Problems in SSH to 2 of my VirtualBox VMs (for mininet setup)

Tags: networking, ssh, virtualbox, virtual-machine, port-forwarding

I'm trying to set up a Mininet environment with SDN setup, each under a separate VirtualBox VM(`mininet@mininet` and `media@odl`) (using [this](http://www.brianlinkletter.com/using-the-opendaylight-sdn-controller-with-the-mininet-network-emulator/) tutorial- pretty strait forward). First adapter in VMs by default is NAT, and I also added a second adapter under `host-only`.

However, on my host (non-VM) machine, I can not SSH to any of those two VMs.

I again googled and followed port forwarding recommendation [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/145997/trying-to-ssh-to-local-vm-ubuntu-with-putty) for the first adapter (i.e. NAT) on @odl just to test (for NAT adapter). And the port forwarding on odl's configuration looks similar to this (btw I chose 'allow all' for that mode- no difference though).

[image]

However, still no chance to ssh to the VM. When I do `ssh media@127.0.1.1`, I get permission error:

```
odl@127.0.1.1's password: 
Permission denied, please try again.
```

**What is going wrong? How can I access those VMs?** Not only from host, the `mininet` should also see `odl`.

This is odl's ifconfig:
[image]